# How to call nodeJS method from client side on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to download an image on my server using node js when client clicks on a button. I am able to run this function from backend. But I have no idea on how to accomplish this for front end.

This is my backend nodeJS code:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

 request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', 
 callback);
 });
 };

// invoke the function
  download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
 });
```

This is the button in html

```
<button onclick = "download('/...link-to-image.jpg')"></button>
```

I know I can use form for this, but I don't want to refresh the page. Should I use jquery forms for ajaxSubmit??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short code hope it helps

`<a href="file/path" download>download</a>`

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use ajax in order to call your api. Click on button will do an ajax call to your api and your api will do whatever you want.

Try to follow this its pretty easy

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp